# Running VSLAM on stereo data

Tags: ros, vslam, vslam-system

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run VSLAM on Stereo Data. When trying to roslaunch stereo_vslam.launch, I'm getting this error message
**cannot launch node of type [vslam_system/stereo_vslam_node]**

I suspect it has to do with files: find holidays.tree, holidays.weights, data/calonder.rtc
on the line
.....find vocabulary_tree)/holidays.tree $(find vocabulary_tree)/holidays.weights $(find vslam_system)/data/calonder.rtc ......

I don't find this file on the server ( holidays.tree, holidays.weights, data/calonder.rtc).
Do I need them? If yes, how do I get them? Where Do I start?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10024/running-vslam-on-stereo-data/) by [maz](https://answers.ros.org/users/575/maz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You actually need these files to launch stereo_vslam_node. They should be at /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/vslam/vocabulary_tree folder. If not, try to upgrade the vslam package.

Then, you can download the bag file mentioned in the tutorial:

roscd vslam_system
wget http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/vslam_system/vslam_tutorial.bag

but according to my experience you have to fix the bag file before using it:

rosbag fix vslam_tutorial.bag vslam_tutorial_fixed.bag

and then you can play it before launching the vslam node:

rosbag play --clock vslam_tutorial_fixed.bag

Regards

Jordi

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2011-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1